# How to change the location of ElevateButton to the right side, which properties or widgets help me to do that?

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't want the button to be in the centre instead of that I want to change the location of the button to the right and I don't know how to do that. I need some help

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.blue,
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 15),
          ),
          onPressed: (() {}),
          child: Text(
            'Projects',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

I tried to use Padding, but I'm new to Flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Align widget like

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  child: ElevatedButton(
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the ElevatedButton in Row and add Expanded(child: SizedBox.expand()) as first child to this row and ElevatedButton as 2nd child.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `crossAxisAlignment` to your column:

```dart
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.blue,
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 15),
          ),
          onPressed: (() {}),
          child: Text(
            'Projects',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ],
```

If this doesn't work, you can also do this:

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Container()),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.blue,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 15),
                  ),
                  onPressed: (() {}),
                  child: Text(
                    'Projects',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the widget tree, how its aligned. Your `Padding` widget may be wrapped inside some widget which is center aligned. So assuming that your `Padding` widget alignment is not affected by any parent widget. Here is solution to this.

There are multiple approaches for that. For example,

1. You can add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,` in `Column` attributes.
2. You can wrap your `ElevatedButton` inside a `Row` and add the `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,` attributes.
3. You can use `Align` class to make it work.

Just like this, here i have used both `Column` and `Row` alignments for the sake of demonstration. But you can use whatever suits best to your situation.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.blue,
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 15),
          ),
          onPressed: (() {}),
          child: Text(
            'Projects',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I tried the third approach and it works, thanks